# nVidia 325.15 and Bumblebee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I will be receiving a laptop with an nVidia gtx 780M (so, unfortunately, Optimus) and I was wondering if it was possible, on Ubuntu 13.04, to make it run with the newest nVidia drivers (325.15) + Bumblebee or if the 325.15 is still Arch Linux only.

If the answer is "Yes, it's quite possible" I'd like to know which repo I should use for such a feat.

Thank you very much for your answers and time: I'd really appreciate Ubuntu and its simplicity and I would bother me very much to have to switch to Arch Linux for just a driver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering myself so that anyone interested may check this out:

actually it should be possible to have the nVidia 325.xx drivers on Ubuntu using the xorg-edgers repository (see https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa and http://www.linux.org/threads/nvidia-optimus-on-linux.4415/, the latter it's about Oz Unity , but it's an Ubuntu-derived distro having Ubuntu 13.04 at its core...).

As soon as I've got the aforementioned laptop under my hands I will try a dual boot and the xorg-edgers+bumblebee setup and let you know how it will end!

Any other answer (maybe also experiences of people which have tried to do such a feat with the 780M) are quite appreciated!

Comment: Did you get your laptop? Can you describe your experiences with bumbleebee and nvidia 325 pls. I am currently running bumblebee with nvidia 319 and it seems to work fine. But I still want to upgrade to 325 for better performance.

Comment: Still didn't get my laptop, unfortunately. But to be absolutely fair I was also considering in switching to Manjaro Linux: Arch-based, rolling release, nVidia 325.15 drivers included, easy installation and the captivating catchphrase "runs Optimus out of the box"...